# Parent-child IPC on Windows using Python and custom file descriptors

Tags: python, windows, ipc

I want to create a child process with `subprocess.Popen` and read a message from it using custom file descriptor. I have two files:

`parent.py`:

```
import os
import subprocess

r_fd, w_fd = os.pipe()
os.set_inheritable(w_fd, True)

print(f'parent.py - Writing fd: {w_fd}. Is inheritable - {os.get_inheritable(w_fd)}')

fo = os.fdopen(r_fd)

with subprocess.Popen(['python', 'child.py'], close_fds=False):
    print(fo.read())

fo.close()
```

`child.py`:

```
import os

inherited_fd = 4

try:
    is_inheritable = os.get_inheritable(inherited_fd)
except OSError as err:
    print(f'child.py - os.get_inheritable error: {err}')

fo = os.fdopen(inherited_fd)
fo.write('hello')
fo.close()
```

As far as I understand the documentation about [Inheritance of File Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#fd-inheritance), all I need is make my writing fd inheritable and set `Popen`'s `close_fds` to `False`. Then I can use it in my child process.

Executing `python parent.py` gives the following output:

```
parent.py - Writing fd: 4. Is inheritable - True
child.py - os.get_inheritable error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\temp\child.py", line 10, in <module>
    fo = os.fdopen(inherited_fd)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\os.py", line 1029, in fdopen
    return io.open(fd, mode, buffering, encoding, *args, **kwargs)
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

I do not mind hardcoded fd now, also it is not necessary for me to use `Popen`. The only important condition is that I need to use custom fd and I am interested in making it work on Windows. I use Python 3.11. Do I miss something?